# Permalink issue

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

There is a problem in the page permalink in wordpress when i add page name it's permalink has to show like ["www.example.com/page-name](http://www.example.com/page-name)" instead of this it shows like 
[www.example.com/page-name-2](http://www.example.com/page-name) or -3 when i try to change it it turns back i think maybe this is a page but when i access the link  it shows that it is a media file permalink of an image . Is there any solution of this sort of problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is possible quite easily.

1. Go to Media Library
2. Find the image this link refers to
3. When you click on it choose "Edit more details" in the bottom right corner
4. In the top right part of this page click "Screen Options" and enable the "Slug" checkbox
5. Scroll down to the slug box and change the slug name to whatever you like.
6. Click "Update" and voila

Answer (score 0):

That sounds as if a page with that permalink already exists - check for it in the "All PAGES" list view *and* also inside the trash (for older, deleted versions)

Comment: already check this, no page with same name and permalink i check the permalink it show's the permalink belongs to a mediafile please have a look

Comment: then take a look at the list of media files (and also inside the trash there)